# NIFI:cron scheuling pattern

Tags: cron, apache-nifi

I want to run  my nifi processor  daily at 00:00 i use  expression like  this :0 0 * * *?  but it  throws  exception like this:

[image]

also  here is  several  subject i am interested in:

1. can i  use cron on  groups   i have added
2. 2.can  i use any parameter (for  example i=2) whcih will  help me start and  stop processors in  evry 2  hours  after other processors
   have  started( i want to use  any parameter 
   (in my case i ) which will start processor  after
   several  hours other  processors  have started it's  work)

Answer (score 1):

First of all the expression you have provided would not run daily at 00:00, it would run every hour. The third value in the expression is the hour value, and having it as the special character '*' means it runs every hour, replace this with '0' would change it to run at midnight.

So the new correct expression would be: `0 0 0 1/1 * ?`

From what I can see from the expression you are providing it may be throwing the exception due to the spacing of the last value of the cron expression. The expression you provided, : "0 0 * * *?", does not have a space before the last question mark. This may cause an issue since the standard expected format is for all values to be separated by a space. Using the cron expression listed above should give you a valid trigger

Comment: Do  you know how  can i  start  processor after  an   hour failure  happens?

Comment: @sakosako Hi Sako, unfortunately I don't have experience when it comes to  apache nifi, I could only help with the exception that was being thrown due to the invalid cron format.